# VBA for Excel color codes

Tags: vba, excel

In object properties it is possible to set custom colors that are formatted eg. &H00893959&.  Playing around with this it seems to be linked to RGB or such, but I can't find much logic.  Does anyone know how these codes work?

Comment: Thanks for joining Stack Overflow.  Without your code showing what problem you're encountering, it's difficult for us to help you.  VBA has a function RGB() that returns a color based on the Red, Green, Blue parameter values.  To help us help you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Write a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no VBA code involved in this case.  This parameter is set in the 'properties' dialog box.  eg. UserForm, BackColor

Comment: By 'code' in the above question, I was referring to the '&H00893959&' which is set in the BackColor property box

Comment: Like I recommended, see the tour and how to write a good question.  You're talking about the properties dialog for a user form or other object.  If you want to set a custom color and you know the hex code from the web, then there are a multitude of sites that will convert the Web Hex codes to RGB.  Just Google them. Good luck and happy coding

Comment: Yes, in the properties dialog box for userform - that is what I stated above.  I read those pages some time ago but don't see how their content would change my question format.  I was just seeing if anyone could explain how the color 'code' above works as I've not been able to find any explanations online.  I will search web hex code and see where that goes.

Answer (score 3):

That's most likely a hex representation of the three color bytes.

- Numbers *prefixed* with `&H` are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (aka Base 16).
- Numbers *suffixed* with `&` are [unsigned integers](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681009-RESOLVED-I-thought-amp-H-was-shorthand-for-hex).

You'd see it more commonly expressed as an HTML Color Code without the extra characters as **`#893959`**, which is the color below.  *(More about this color [here](http://www.color-hex.com/color/893959).)*:

[image: color]

---

Here's a VBA Function to extract the 3 color bytes and convert from hex to decimal (for use with Excel/VBA) using the [RGB Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/rgb-function).

```
Function Hex2RGB(hex As String) As Long
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        r = .Hex2Dec(Mid(hex, 5, 2))
        g = .Hex2Dec(Mid(hex, 7, 2))
        b = .Hex2Dec(Mid(hex, 9, 2))
    End With
    Hex2RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function


Sub Demo()
    Const hexColor = "&H00893959&"
    Debug.Print "The RBG (decimal) interpretation of '" _
        & hexColor & "' is " & Hex2RGB(hexColor) & "."  'returns 5847433
End Sub
```